# Make Regex Match word containing spetial characters

Tags: c#, regex

My Code is like this:

```
string currentPageSlug = "securities/EBR#03L$ZZZ";
string patern= @"securities/(\w+)[\#\$]";
string res = Regex.Match(currentPageSlug, patern).Value;
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

which gives me this result:

```
securities/EBR#
```

but I want to get:

```
securities/EBR#03L$ZZZ
```

whole word including all special characters (# and $ and maybe others too)
my regex pattern does not seem to work.

Comment: `.*` will match everything ;) (which is basically what you're saying you want). But... your pattern suggests you want to capture everything after `securities/` - is that it?

Comment: Well I wouldn't use alternation here. Maybe `string patern= @"securities/\S+";` would be better. If a nonwhitespace class is too greedy for you you may try `[\w\p{S}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches words followed by a single special character. You need to include `[#$]` in the repeating construct `+`, like this:

```
string patern= @"securities/((?:\w|[#$])+)";
```

Note that since `#` and `$` are used inside a *character class*, it is not necessary to escape them with a backslash `\`.